# Moving remote folder named by local variable

Tags: bash, ssh, mv

I'm trying to move a remote directory whose name contains a value which is a single digit number stored in a local variable.

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1 'mv /etc/folder_* /etc/folder_$value'
```

However $value isn't parsed, i've tried putting quotes and double quotes?

Comment: What is the output of `echo "$value"`. What do you mean by "not getting parsed" and how do you know?

Comment: echo $value can be a number between 1 and 9 what I mean is that $value isn't added to the end of the new directory name.

Comment: @Lurch: if using double quotes (i.e. `ssh root@1.1.1.1 "mv /etc/folder_* /etc/folder_$value"`) does not solve the problem, it means that `value` is not assigned or is empty. Try putting `echo "$value"` before the command, and show us how you assign `value`

Comment: Also, show the error you are getting. Even if **you** don't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use double quotes instead of single quotes.
So that the shell command can interpolate your locally defined variable "value".
So use instead:

```
ssh root@1.1.1.1 "mv /etc/folder_* /etc/folder_$value"
```

Example output for when I tested this:
(variable NROFLINES is defined locally, equal to 4)

```
cristi@ubuntu:~$ ssh archtln@192.168.174.165 'ls | head -$NROFLINES'
archtln@192.168.174.165's password: 
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
examples.desktop
Music
Pictures
Public
Templates
tmp

cristi@ubuntu:~$ ssh archtln@192.168.174.165 "ls | head -$NROFLINES"
archtln@192.168.174.165's password: 
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
examples.desktop
```